# Merge 2 data frames and allocate rows from a non join column equally

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames of different lengths and with one common column. What I need to do is combine them, but in a way that equally distributes values from a non-common column. So if we have Users:

```
User    Category
John    A
John    D
Will    A
Will    E
Bea     P
Bea     E
Sarah   A
Sarah   B
```

And claims:

```
Category    Claim
A             1
A             2
B             3
B             4
D             5
D             6
D             7
D             8
D             9
D             10
D             11
D             12
A             13
A             14
A             15
A             16
A             17
A             18
E             19
E             20
E             21
E             22
E             23
E             24
E             25
E             26
E             27
E             28
P             29
P             30
P             31
P             32
P             33
P             34
```

I want to provide an equal number of claims for each User based on Category - i.e. A claims would be split up between 3 users evenly.

Comment: `I want to provide an equal number of claims for each User based on Category - ie A claims would be split up between 3 users evenly. It would be even better to weight it based on the category a user is matched with, i.e. John would get fewer A claims than another user because he is the sole user for D.` So... split up A claims equally except not actually equally? Sounds like you are not clear yet on what you want! Can you please provide your expected output? I think it would help both us and you clarify what you have in mind. We can't design your weighting scheme for you.

Comment: Splitting evenly will get me where I need to go.  I will update my question to keep this from being convoluted.  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, explanations are in the comments:

```
library("dplyr")

# Creating a "user number" which is their ID among 
# other users having this category... When allocating claims, we'll know
# "this is user 2 out of 3 for category A, I need to assign the second third of the A claims."
users <- 
  users %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  arrange(Category) %>%
  mutate(user_number = 1:n(), 
         total_users = n())

# Same thing for claims: this will allow us to identify the "second third of A claims"
claims <- 
  claims %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(claim_number = 1:n(),
         total_claims = n())

user_claims <- 
  users %>%
  # full join gives all the XXX claims to everyone in category XXX
  full_join(claims) %>%
  # We only keep the fraction of the claims that "belongs" to the user
  filter(claim_number > total_claims * (user_number - 1) / total_users, 
         claim_number <= total_claims * (user_number) / total_users)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for.  Just curious, is there a quick way to weight it by how many claims a person has coming their way?  Like if John had an inordinate amount of D claims one day he'd get fewer A claims?  No problem if not, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

claim %>% 
  count(Category, name="Claims") %>% 
  left_join(user, ., by=c("Category")) %>% 
  add_count(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Claims = Claims / n) %>% 
  select(-n)

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   User  Category Claims
#>   <fct> <fct>     <dbl>
#> 1 John  A          2.67
#> 2 John  D          8   
#> 3 Will  A          2.67
#> 4 Will  E          5   
#> 5 Bea   P          6   
#> 6 Bea   E          5   
#> 7 Sarah A          2.67
#> 8 Sarah B          2
```

***Data:***

```r
claim <- structure(list(Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
                                               3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
                                            .Label = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "P"), 
                                             class = "factor"), 
                        Claim = 1:34), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))

user <- structure(list(User = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), 
                                       .Label = c("Bea", "John", "Sarah", "Will"), 
                                        class = "factor"), 
                       Category = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
                                           .Label = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "P"), 
                                            class = "factor")), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Ah, do you think OP just wanted to _count_ the claims? I was totally overthinking it. @nre1313 Please provide an expected output next time.

Comment: @antoine-sac honestly I am not sure, OP should provide a minimal example (not this many rows) with desired output, but this just made more sense to me. Anyhow, your solution is a good one. It can get a bit shorter but that may adversely affect readability. Cheers +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` way:

```
Users <- data.table(User = rep(c("John","Will","Bea","Sarah"),each = 2), Category = c("A","D","A","E","P","E","A","B"))

set.seed(1)
Claims <- data.table(Category = sample(c("A","D","E","P"), replace = TRUE, 34), Claim = 1:34)


claims_joined <- merge(Users, Claims, by = "Category", allow.cartesian = TRUE)

claims_joined[, mod_base := uniqueN(User), by = .(Category)]
claims_joined <- claims_joined[, .(User = User[1L + (.GRP %% mod_base)][1]), by = .(Category, Claim)]

dcast(claims_joined, Category ~ User, fun.aggregate = length)
   Category Bea John Sarah Will
1:        A   0    2     3    3
2:        D   0   11     0    0
3:        E   3    0     0    4
4:        P   8    0     0    0
```

You essentially do a full outer join, then set up a index that increments for each claim. You then modulo that index by the number of users in that category, which is then used to pick a rotating user for each claim within the category